# How to use a compared property's Display Name with the Compare attribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

Here are the two properties being compared:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Current Password")]
public string Current { get; set; }

[Required]
[Compare("New")]
[Display(Name = "New Password")]
public string New { get; set; }
```

The validation message reads as follows:

```
'Confirm Password' and 'New' do not match.
```

How can I get this attribute to use the Display Name of the `New` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a while to figure this out, but apparently I was using the wrong `Compare` attribute.

My initial declaration was using the `Compare` found in  `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`, while the proper one is defined in `System.Web.Mvc`.

It's pretty stupid that `DataAnnotations.Compare` doesn't carry the same functionality, but then again it's pretty stupid that there are two `Compare` attributes to begin with.

THIS is the proper implementation:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "New Password")]
public string New { get; set; }

[System.Web.Mvc.Compare("New")]
[Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

Hope this helps somebody else, because it sure did frustrate the hell out of me. C'est la vie.

Comment: The semi-redundancy of those (and other) attributes has always annoyed me, too.